# Why can't I clear data after click on submit button?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-forms

I make it simple:

I work with google form as my database for now.

After I added reset ability to the submit button, the JS file it sends me again to the response page of google form.

Can you help ? Thanks

```
<form id="form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/2/d/e/1FAIpQLSeBJHw1Q6YlwO_0s2OgMhuyQEj4PLvToM1N1G5BEYQRiZlCLQ/formResponse">
                <label for="">It's FREE</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name" class="inputs" id="input1" name="entry.1045366435">
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="inputs" id="input2" name="entry.1398681060">
                <textarea cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Message" id="input3" name="entry.403219718"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send">
            </form>
```

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    alert("Thanks for signing up. We will contact you as soon as we can.");
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/u/2/d/e/1FAIpQLSeBJHw1Q6YlwO_0s2OgMhuyQEj4PLvToM1N1G5BEYQRiZlCLQ/formResponse",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#form')[0].reset()
          },
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Submission successful');
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('Submission failed: ' + error);
        }

    });
});
//Alert + Disable google form response page
```

Comment: why do you have two submit handlers? reset is on the form, not the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should not have two different submit handlers, just use one. Second reset is on the form, not the inputs.

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#form')[0].reset()
  console.log('Submission successful');
},
```

Comment: Hey, I changed it (You can see in the post). I see the alert but Nothing getting clear or reset in the forms. Thanks.

Comment: You added a second success handler..... that is not correct. SHould be one just like how I posted it....

Answer (score 1):

reset() is a method against form.

Thus you will need to select the form instead.

```
document.getElementById("form").reset();
```

Comment: Hey, I changed it (You can see in the post). I see the alert but Nothing getting clear or reset in the forms. Thanks.

Comment: could you do a console.log(document.getElementById("form")) and check if the correct form is selected?

Comment: Submission failed: 
ptrack-v1.3.1-engagedtime-slots-video.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pixel' of undefined
    at Object.e.engagedTime.sendHeartbeat [as heartbeatFn] (ptrack-v1.3.1-engagedtime-slots-video.js:5)
    at Object.n.sendHeartbeat (ptrack-v1.3.1-engagedtime-slots-video.js:5)
    at ptrack-v1.3.1-engagedtime-slots-video.js:5

Comment: This looks like a separate issue in your ptrack-v1.3.1-engagedtime-slots-video.js file that stopped your entire script. You may need to troubleshoot this first